Error during the building 'node-canvas' on arm64 M1 CPU
I'm getting the following error on Mac with M1 CPU:
 I'm unable to build nodejs app with 'node-canvas' npm package, because  Error: dlopen(/Users/..../node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/..../node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/..../node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node' (no such file), '/Users/..../node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
I installed brew canvas dependencies:
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg pixman
I also set following path:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/pixman/lib/pkgconfig"
I also tried to rebuild from source-codes:
npm install --build-from-source
I also removed and installed again canvas package:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json npm install

But still I'm getting the same error related to arm64 architecture.
notice:
nodejs is installed with nvm
nodejs version: v22.11.0
nvm version: 0.39.7

Thanks for help.

The problem was found with Meteor nodejs, which after update was change from arm64 to incorrect x64 platform. Current nodejs platform you can simple validate by:
meteor node -p "process.arch" (correct result for M1: arm64)
If the result is incorrect (x64) continue by following steps:
1. Reinstall Meteor.js
cd
rm -rf meteor
curl https://install.meteor.com/\?release\=3.1 | sh
cd <your project folder>
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
meteor update
meteor update --all-packages
meteor npm install

2. Install canvas prerequisities
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg pixman

3. Install and rebuild canvas package
meteor npm install canvas
meteor npm rebuild canvas --from-source-code

4. Validate canvas package
node -e "require('canvas')"
// result must be empty (without Error message)

Thanks a lot for help to @errorau

To fix the node-canvas build issue on your M1 Mac:
Reinstall Node.js for ARM64:
nvm uninstall v22.11.0
arch -arm64 nvm install v22.11.0

Install Dependencies for ARM64:
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg pixman

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/homebrew/opt/pixman/lib/pkgconfig"

Clean Reinstall Canvas:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
npm rebuild canvas --build-from-source

for result
node -e "require('canvas')"


Thanks a lot @errorau, I followed your instructions and when I will use 'npm rebuild canvas --build-from-source' => node -e "require('canvas')" it works without error, BUT: when do the same from meteor.js framework 'meteor npm rebuild canvas --build-from-source' => meteor node -e "require('canvas')" I still get the same error related to architecture :-(

Helloe @errorau, together with your recommendations I found, that on Meteor 3.0.4 canvas package works and on Meteor 3.1 (latest) it's getting those error.
